# Cannot assign "3": "StudentsEnrolledSubject.Subject_Section_Teacher" must be a "SubjectSectionTeacher" instance

Tags: django, django-models

Django signal **Cannot assign "3": "StudentsEnrolledSubject.Subject_Section_Teacher" must be a "SubjectSectionTeacher" instance.** i have foreignkey **Subject_Section_Teacher** in **StudentsEnrolledSubject** related in **SubjectSectionTeacher**

in this line  **Subject_Section_Teacher=each.Employee_Users.id** is my error

I have this models.py

```
class StudentsEnrolledSubject(models.Model):
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentsEnrollmentRecord, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subject_Section_Teacher = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSectionTeacher, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    @receiver(pre_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def get_older_instance(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance._old_instance = StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        except StudentsEnrollmentRecord.DoesNotExist:
            instance._old_instance = None

    @receiver(post_save, sender=StudentsEnrollmentRecord)
    def create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if not created:
            older_instance = instance._old_instance
            if older_instance.Courses != instance.Courses or \
                    older_instance.Section != instance.Section or \
                    older_instance.Education_Levels != instance.Education_Levels:

                StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.filter(
                    Students_Enrollment_Records=instance
                ).delete()
            else:
                return None

        teachers = SubjectSectionTeacher.objects.filter(Sections=instance.Section,
                                                        Education_Levels=instance.Education_Levels,
                                                        Courses=instance.Courses)
        for each in teachers:
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
                Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                Subject_Section_Teacher=each.Employee_Users.id)

class SubjectSectionTeacher(models.Model):
    School_Year = models.ForeignKey(SchoolYear, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    Courses= models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Sections= models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Subjects= models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    Employee_Users= models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message states, you are trying to assign an integer (the teacher's user id) to a field that should be a `SubjectSectionTeacher` instance. All you ned to do is leave off the `.Employee_Users.id`, and you'll solve this error. I'm also going to modify your `each` variable to be `teacher` to make it more clear.

```py
# ...
        for teacher in teachers:
            StudentsEnrolledSubject.objects.create(
                Students_Enrollment_Records=instance,
                Subject_Section_Teacher=teacher)
```

Comment: you have a point mr @Greg but i want to get the id of EmployeeUser which it is the foreign key of Employee_Users, that is why i use ""each.Employee_Users.id""

Comment: You don't need to set the foreign keys. This is one of the things Django does for you. As the error clearly states, you should be assigning the SubjectSectionTeacher object directly.

Comment: then how can i distinct the data?

Comment: i have 4 data save in my SubjectSectionTeacher"" with the same section, educationlevel and courses,

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a separate question. Has this answer solved the error?

Comment: no, because 4 data saves in StudentsEnrolledSubject, i just need one that is why i use this Subject_Section_Teacher=each.Employee_Users.id